# .net core tests can't run beside others

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a test project with .net core 1.1 and 3 with .net 4.6.2. Both projects use xUnit entirely. 
Both project show up in the TestRunner run when I start them independently. But when I start all tests, just one type is executed, either the test in the core project or the one in the .net 4.6.2 project.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are the .net 4.6.2 projects "sdk projects"? Meaning they are created using `<Project Sdk="..">` and have a `PackageReference` to `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`? Also, I'm assuming you use VS 2017?

Comment: Yes I use VS2017. The projects are created by the Visual Studio Unit Test (.net Framework) Template. I assume that they are not sdk projects then? How can I check that? Also I tried if it helps when I add the Test.Sdk Package, but had the same result.

Comment: You can edit the project file.. Or create a new .net core test project and change the `<TargetFramework>` from `netcoreapp1.1` to `net462` in the csproj file

Comment: Ah, I see. So are these two types of tests (the classic and the ones over the test sdk) who are not compatible side by side in the Vs TestRunner?

Comment: There are two types of projects that run via different "project systems" in VS and the test runner is limited in some ways and I remember there have been some GitHub issues on it, but I don't know the exact answer here so just giving options to try..

Comment: I just tried this. It works so far for the execution. But when I make a rebuild so that it rediscovers the tests it won't show me my .net core 1.1 project. I have then to build this manually so that it shows up in the Test Explorer. Then the execution works. After the next Rebuild it is again removed. Still an improvment so far :)